# Is the variance of sum of two random variables always less than sum of the variance?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ be two arbitrary random variables. Is that always true that $Var(X+Y)\le Var(X)+Var(Y)$? Or if there any relation between these two sides, for example, multiply one of the by a constant?

Comment: Look up the term "covariance."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_correlated_variables

Answer (score 4):

Set $Y=X$ to violate the inequality.

Answer (score 2):

$Var(X+Y)\leq 2\left(Var(X)+Var(Y)\right)$, since for any $a,b\in\Re$ we have $(a+b)^2\leq 2(a^2+b^2)$.

Note that in general the inequality cannot be "tightened": if $X=Y$ we have $Var(X+Y)=2\left(Var(X)+Var(Y)\right)$, so in general $Var(X+Y)\nleq Var(X)+Var(Y)$.

By the same token, $Var(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)\leq n\sum_{i=1}^n Var(X_i)$, with equality holding if $X_i=X_j$ for all $i,j$.